# Bluetooth GATT data getting corrupted in flight

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm using [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) to consume my [bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno) peripheral. The data buffer I return in my `onReadRequest()` callback is somehow getting corrupted when it gets to my noble `Characteristic.read()`. I dump the buffer right before the callback in my `onReadRequest()` and I dump it right away when I get it in `Characteristic.read()`:

#### Consumer

```
...
Characteristic.read((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {     
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
...
```

#### Producer

```
...
const bleno = require('bleno');

const flags = {
    a: 1 << 0,
    b: 1 << 1,
    c: 1 << 2
  },
  numBytesInReturnData = 18,
  supportedFlags = flags.a | flags.b | flags.c,
  accelPrecision = Math.pow(10, 5),
  bPrecision = Math.pow(10, 3);

module.exports = class DataCharacteristic extends bleno.Characteristic {
  constructor(pin) {
    super({
      uuid: '1234',
      properties: ['read'],
      descriptors: [new bleno.Descriptor({
        uuid: '2901',
        value: 'blah'
      })]
    });
    this._hardware = hardware;
    this._hasData = false;
    this._dataBuffer = new Buffer.allocUnsafe(numBytesInReturnData).fill(0);
  }

  onReadRequest(offset, callback) {
    if (!offset) {
      this._hasData = false;
      this._dataBuffer.fill(0);
      Promise.all([
          this._hardware.getA),
          this._hardware.getB(),
          this._hardware.getC(),
        ]).then((responses) => {
          this._dataBuffer.writeUInt8(supportedFlags, 0);

          this._dataBuffer.writeUInt8(responses[0], 1);
          this._dataBuffer.writeInt32LE(responses[0] * aPrecision, 2, true);
          this._dataBuffer.writeInt32LE(responses[2].x * accelPrecision, 6, true); //accel
          this._dataBuffer.writeInt32LE(responses[2].y * accelPrecision, 10, true);
          this._dataBuffer.writeInt32LE(responses[2].z * accelPrecision, 14, true);

          console.log(this._dataBuffer);

          this._hasData = true;
          callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, this._dataBuffer);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error('Error when reading hardware data', err);
          callback(this.RESULT_UNLIKELY_ERROR);
        });
    } else if (this._hasData) { //reading a second time for rest of data
      callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, this._dataBuffer.slice(offset));
    } else {
      callback(this.RESULT_ATTR_NOT_LONG);
    }
  }
}
```

Producer outupt

`<Buffer 07 00 00 00 00 00 c2 c9 ff ff e4 2c 00 00 1c 47 0f 00>`

consumer outupt

`<Buffer 07 00 00 00 00 00 c2 c9 ff ff 5f 34 00 00 5f 43 0f 00>`

As you can see only part of the buffer gets corrupted. Why does this happen?

Comment: Could it be that the consumer is simply getting the messages in a different order than the producer is sending them?  I don't really know much about the messaging system you're using.  Maybe add a counter to the message to see if they're coming in the same order?

Answer (score 0):

Might you be reading immediately after the peripheral notifies or indicates? If so, it may be that the data being passed to your read callback is actually data from the last notify or indicate. See this issue [here](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble/issues/661).